# SQL Get entire row based on minimum value of calculated column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with multiple values of bed ID with different statuses, something like this.

```
PID     |  term_id   |  student_id   |  bed_id   | status    |  Comment
--------+------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+----------------
1       |  29        |  1234         |  751      | Canceled  |  Not this one
2       |  29        |  1234         |  751      | Active    |  This one
3       |  29        |  531          |  752      | Active    |  This one too
4       |  29        |  823          |  752      | Canceled  |  Not this one either
5       |  29        |  525          |  753      | Canceled  |  But this one too
```

I want a query to get a single row for each bed_id based on the value of status.
I've tried:

```
SELECT *,MIN(CASE sample.status
                         WHEN 'Arrived' THEN 1
                         WHEN 'Active' THEN 2
                         WHEN 'Pending Approval' THEN 3
                         WHEN 'Pending Confirmation' THEN 4
                         WHEN 'Pending Manual' THEN 5
                         WHEN 'Denied' THEN 6
                         WHEN 'Canceled' THEN 7
                END) AS StatusOrder
FROM sample
WHERE (sample.term_id = 29)
GROUP BY bed_id
```

But it gives me:

```
PID  |  term_id |  student_id |  bed_id | status    |  Comment           | StatusOrder
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  29      |  1234       |  751    | Canceled  |  Not this one      | 2
3    |  29      |  531        |  752    | Active    |  This one too      | 2
5    |  29      |  525        |  753    | Canceled  |  But this one too  | 7
```

(The StatusOrder value is right, but the rest of the row does not correspond to the row with minimum StatusOrder value)

What I want is:

```
PID  |  term_id |  student_id |  bed_id | status    |  Comment           | StatusOrder
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2    |  29      |  1234       |  751    | Active    |  This one          | 2
3    |  29      |  531        |  752    | Active    |  This one too      | 2
5    |  29      |  525        |  753    | Canceled  |  But this one too  | 7
```

I've read [MySQL MIN/MAX all row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293778/mysql-min-max-all-row)
and also tried this:

```
SELECT *,MIN(CASE sample.status
                         WHEN 'Arrived' THEN 1
                         WHEN 'Active' THEN 2
                         WHEN 'Pending Approval' THEN 3
                         WHEN 'Pending Confirmation' THEN 4
                         WHEN 'Pending Manual' THEN 5
                         WHEN 'Denied' THEN 6
                         WHEN 'Canceled' THEN 7
                END) AS StatusOrder
FROM  sample
WHERE ( 
        (sample.term_id = 29) AND (
        StatusOrder = CASE sample.status
                         WHEN 'Arrived' THEN 1
                         WHEN 'Active' THEN 2
                         WHEN 'Pending Approval' THEN 3
                         WHEN 'Pending Confirmation' THEN 4
                         WHEN 'Pending Manual' THEN 5
                         WHEN 'Denied' THEN 6
                         WHEN 'Canceled' THEN 7
                END)
       )
GROUP BY bed_id
```

But this produces an error. (Also tried replacing StatusOrder with the full CASE statement)

NOTE:  I've simplified the actual table which has many more columns.  But basically I need access to the whole row that corresponds to the row with the lowest StatusOrder (determined by my case statement) for each bed_id.

Using MySQL 5.5

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d33a2/14 Use this for testing,since i was late to the party.

Comment: Thanks Mihai!  This is very helpful / sqlfiddle is very neat!  I will use this for future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Below Query works, but it's better to consider replace the column status with `status_code` with the code, and have a separate table `status(status_code,description)`  {denormalise}

And indexing (`term_id,statUs_code`).

by this, we can just self join. Instead creating a view like this.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *,(CASE sample.status
                         WHEN 'Arrived' THEN 1
                         WHEN 'Active' THEN 2
                         WHEN 'Pending Approval' THEN 3
                         WHEN 'Pending Confirmation' THEN 4
                         WHEN 'Pending Manual' THEN 5
                         WHEN 'Denied' THEN 6
                         WHEN 'Canceled' THEN 7
                END) AS status_code FROM SAMPLE
  WHERE sample.term_id = 29
) my_view1,
(SELECT BED_ID,MIN(CASE sample.status
                         WHEN 'Arrived' THEN 1
                         WHEN 'Active' THEN 2
                         WHEN 'Pending Approval' THEN 3
                         WHEN 'Pending Confirmation' THEN 4
                         WHEN 'Pending Manual' THEN 5
                         WHEN 'Denied' THEN 6
                         WHEN 'Canceled' THEN 7
                END) AS status_code FROM SAMPLE
 WHERE sample.term_id = 29
 GROUP BY BED_ID
) my_view2
WHERE my_view1.bed_id = my_view2.bed_id
 AND  my_view1.status_code = my_view2.status_code
```

Comment: This is working!  Thanks so much!  Am I correct to understand that my original problem is caused by SELECTing non-aggregated columns (*) that are not in my GROUP BY clause--which produces indeterminate results in MySQL?  You solve this by using a separate view for the grouping that only selects bed_id (which is in the group by clause) and the aggregate column then joining the two views.  Even if I separate status/priority out into another table, wouldn't I still need the view to avoid the indeterminate situation?

Comment: if you have separate tables,, you dont need the view, but join the table with just creating one view, which has the grouped content of table, and join to the table again with the min of code.

Comment: That makes sense--so I could get rid of my_view1 but would still need to join the second grouped view to the table.  Too much legacy code depends on the existing structure right now--but I will consider this for a future refactoring.  Thanks again!